# How do I stop my DEL command from deleting files with the same names in a subdirectory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So my `del` command deletes two files instead of one only.

My filesystem with the file I wish to delete looks like this (an example):

> ```
> /executable.exe
> /folder/executable.exe
> ```

When I run `del /s /q "executable.exe"`, both executables will be deleted. I'm running Windows 10, any way to stop this happening? I can absolutely not change the second executable's name.

Comment: Err... take out the /s switch?

Comment: remove the `/s`, which stands for "recursive **s**ubdirectories".

Comment: Ugh didn't realise /s did that... Oh well, thanks so much

Comment: Helps to read the help file for the command you are using. `/S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories..`

Comment: When using any of the standard command line commands like `del` and `for` and `ren`, you can get documentation by typing the command followed by ` /?`, as in `del /?`. And **stop** using commands with switches you don't understand before you end up doing something you can't recover from now. Understand what you're doing **before** you do it instead of trying to fix what you fouled up afterward.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to your question are all quite apropos. The solution to your problem is simply to omit the `/S` switch, as this causes the `DEL` command to delete from the current directory, plus all of the subdirectories, all the way down to the bottom of the filesystem.

CMD.EXE offers help for most commands; type the command name followed by `/?` to get the command help (e.g., `DEL /?`). You can also get the same information by typing `HELP` followed by the command of interest, e.g., `HELP DEL`.

You should not use a destructive command (like `DEL`) without first understanding what the command will do. Read the help; that's why it was provided.